# Resource (.resx) data is not saved

Tags: c#, resources

I can't get what's the problem. Please check my code's fragments. Each time when I add resource data, it clears last data and writes new records in .resx. 
For example, Applications.resx has "MyApp1" key with "MyApp1Path" value. Next time if I add "MyApp2" key with "MyApp2Path" value, I notice that {"MyApp1", "MyApp1Path"} doesn't exist.

```
//Adding Application in Applications List
ResourceHelper.AddResource("Applications", _appName, _appPath);
```

Here is ResourceHelper class:

```
public class ResourceHelper
{
    public static void AddResource(string resxFileName, string name, string value)
    {
        using (var resx = new ResXResourceWriter(String.Format(@".\Resources\{0}.resx", resxFileName)))
        {
            resx.AddResource(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is expected, `ResXResourceWriter` just adds nodes, it doesn't append.

However, you could just read the nodes out, and add them again

```
public static void AddResource(string resxFileName, string name, object value)
{
   var fileName = $@".\Resources\{resxFileName}.resx";

   using (var writer = new ResXResourceWriter(fileName))
   {
      if (File.Exists(fileName))
      {
         using (var reader = new ResXResourceReader(fileName))
         {
            var node = reader.GetEnumerator();
            while (node.MoveNext())
            {
               writer.AddResource(node.Key.ToString(), node.Value);
            }
         }
      }

      writer.AddResource(name, value);
   }
}
```

***Disclaimer***, untested and probably needs error checking